# need help casting classes

Tags: java, class, casting

Here is my situation (not actual code, just a rough outline):

```
class Base {
    public static Image img;
}

class A extends Base {
    A() {
        img = "code to get certain image here";
    }
}

class B extends Base {
    B() {
        img = "code to get certain image2 here";
    }
}
```

I have an array of Base some of which however will be A or B. I want to get the instance of img specific to the class. E.g. if it is an instance of A it will display the img defined in A. However I cannot just use if statements as I will be adding many different classes overtime and also I want the code which gets the image to not need to be changed to include more classes.

Comment: Create a `display` method in `Base` and let `A` and `B` override it accordingly. This would normally work except for your case since `Image img` is `static`. Are you aware of the consequences of this design?

Comment: simply pass it in the constructor of the super class. something like `super(img)`

Comment: Like @LuiggiMendoza suggested that usage of the `static` in your posted code must be a typo. If not then you should stop thinking/working on on the overall design and make sure you understand the basic fundamentals of the language first.

Comment: You can't cast classes (or objects), you can only cast references.  It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that won't be possible as long as the `img` field is static.

The truth is, the `img` field will be overwritten whenever you create a new instance, be it of type `A` or `B` and the reason is `img` being static.
Make your `img` non static:

```
class Base {
    public /*static*/ Image img;
}
```

Everything should work out of the box:

```
Base a = new A();
Base b = new B();
a.img; // Contains the image A created
b.img; // Contains the image B created
```

Comment: I need to create lots of instances of both A and B. So img must be static per each class, is there a way to do this? E.g. every instance of A shares the same instance of img which is different to the instance all of B share.

Comment: Remove the `static` will ensure you have one single image instance per instance of `Base`. If you want `A` instances to have different images than instances of `B` than you should move the img property down to the concrete classes.